# Creating an Abyss

Tags: magic, economy, psychology, philosophy, dimensions

I want to create a setting for my story that amplifies the themes of regret and the things we leave behind and feels like it has a grander purpose in the universe. I am drawing inspiration from the [Abyss](https://www.reddit.com/r/Parahumans/comments/ltcl7i/comment/goydo6m/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). In Wild Bow's [Pact](https://pactwebserial.wordpress.com/) and [pale](https://palewebserial.wordpress.com/about/), Essentially, I want to model it as a pay-to-win, survival-of-the-fittest kind of place where individuals must fight to retain their sense of self or face being consumed by the seemingly aware dimension. How can I ensure that this place feels like a genuine representation of the universe's junkyard, where all things eventually fall into ruin and end up in the Abyss? To a smaller extent, how the abyss works in the [River of Commerce](https://mercenary-tributary.tumblr.com/post/111507084826/this-is-finally-done-a-more-concise-description). Solely because of the deepness of that universe and how the abyss affects water. I like the literal metaphor of "sink or swim."

My question is "How do these tormenting entities manifest physically? Are they ethereal or can they interact with the physical world in some way?"

Comment: Making your character's emotion believable to your reader is more of a writing question rather than a world building question.

Comment: Give some examples of "Things we Leave Behind".

Comment: VTC: This is a High Concept Question (too broad, too open-ended and hypothetical, all answers have equal value, see [help/dont-ask], and brainstorming, see [help/on-topic]). We'll help you work out the details of your Abyss, but we won't create it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember a short story where the main character was sucked into a gray realm where bits and pieces of history floated by like phantoms. The space was limitless, and he was constantly beset by images of war and senseless paperwork. Later in the story, someone concluded that it was the place where wasted time went to, so that's very similar to what you want.

To amplify regret, you'd want to show the people bits of their own history. Every mistaken choice or bad call would parade past them, and then maybe the unfortunate consequences that resulted from those decisions.